# Given a vector equation, find the surface area

Tags: vectors, area, cross-product, iterated-integrals

**Question:**

```
r(u,v) = ucosv i + usinv j + v k  
for v and u, 0<=v<=7pi, 0<=u<=1  
Find the surface area.
```

**from Google I got these steps:**

- Find derivative of r w.r.t. u (r_u) and derivative of r w.r.t. v (r_v)
- Find r_u x r_v (cross-product)
- Surface area = ∫∫ ||r_u x r_v|| dA

But I don't understand what is the real meaning(is it a tangent vector? But toward which direction?) of r_u and r_v. Also, where is the ∫∫ ||r_u x r_v|| dA from?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. May I ask where this exercise is from? It is very unlikely that one would have to do such exercise if one has not known what $r_u$ and $r_v$ are and what $\iint \|r_u\times r_v\|\, dA$ is.

Comment: It is from my vector calculus homework, but I think the course only talks about vector function of 1 variable, it is hard for me to imagine what r_v looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One would never be assigned such homework without seeing any *examples* first. What book on vector calculus are you reading?

Comment: Calculus   Early   Transcendentals   by   James   Stewart,   7thedition,   BROOKS/COLE   CENGAGE Learning

Comment: The answer is in *Section 16.7. Surface Integral.*  of the book.